# resignFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a little problem resigning the keyboard. I have a table with two sections. In the second section, I load the class `stationenStartCellNumber` which has a `UITextField`.

When I press anywhere outside of the `UITextField`, I want the keyboard to resign as first responder, and thereby closing the keyboard. It works perfectly inside of my cell, but not on my `UITableView`.

This is my code:
**stationenViewController.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "stationenStartCell.h"
#import "stationenAppDelegate.h"

@interface stationenViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *theTable;

    NSString *stationenPlistPath;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *theTable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *stationenPlistPath;

- (void)copyStationPlist;
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;

@end
```

**stationenViewController.m**:

```
#import "stationenViewController.h"
#import "chooseStationView.h"
#import "chooseArrDepView.h"
#import "stationenStartCellNumber.h"

@implementation stationenViewController

@synthesize theTable;
@synthesize stationenPlistPath;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [theTable reloadData];

    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setAlpha:1];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *bikePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *bikeDocumentsDirectory = [bikePath objectAtIndex:0];
    stationenPlistPath = [bikeDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stationen.plist"];

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stationenPlistPath])
    {
        [self copyStationPlist];
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    NSUInteger returnInt = 2;

    if (section == 1)
    {
        returnInt = 1;
    }

    return returnInt;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] init];

    if(section == 0)
    {
        returnString = @"Search station details";
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        returnString = @"Search train number";
    }

    return returnString;
}   

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"stationenStartCellID";
        stationenStartCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if (cell == nil){
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"stationenStartCell" owner:nil options:nil];

            for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {
                if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[stationenStartCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (stationenStartCell *)currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        [[cell theBackground] setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stationenStartCell_Background.png"]]];
        [[cell theImage] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_checkMark.png"]];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

        if(indexPath.row % 4 == 0)
        {
            [[cell cellName] setText:NSLocalizedString(@"Choose station", @"Main page")];
            [[cell chosenValue] setText:[prefs valueForKey:@"chosenStation"]];

            NSLog(@"Log info: %@", [prefs valueForKey:@"chosenStation"]);

            if([[prefs valueForKey:@"chosenStation"] isEqualToString:@""] || [prefs valueForKey:@"chosenStation"] == nil)
            {
                [[cell theImage] setAlpha:0.2];
            }
            else {
                [[cell theImage] setAlpha:1];
            }
        }

        if(indexPath.row % 4 == 1)
        {
            NSString *searchType = [prefs valueForKey:@"searchType"];
            NSString *theValue = @"";
            if([searchType isEqualToString:@"0"])
            {
                theValue = NSLocalizedString(@"Arrivals", @"Main page");
            }
            else if([searchType isEqualToString:@"1"])
            {
                theValue = NSLocalizedString(@"Departures", @"Main page");
            }

            if([theValue isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                [[cell theImage] setAlpha:0.2];
            }
            else {
                [[cell theImage] setAlpha:1];
            }

            [[cell cellName] setText:NSLocalizedString(@"Choose departure/arrival", @"Main page")];
            [[cell chosenValue] setText:theValue];
        }

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"stationenStartCellNumber";
        stationenStartCellNumber *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil){
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"stationenStartCellNumber" owner:nil options:nil];

            for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {
                if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[stationenStartCellNumber class]])
                {
                    cell = (stationenStartCellNumber *)currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        [[cell theLabel] setText:@"Tåg nr:"];

        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            chooseStationView *chooseStationViewController = [[chooseStationView alloc] initWithNibName:@"chooseStationView" bundle:nil];
            [[self navigationController] pushViewController:chooseStationViewController animated:YES];
            [chooseStationViewController release], chooseStationViewController = nil;
        }
        else {
            chooseArrDepView *chooseArrDepViewController = [[chooseArrDepView alloc] initWithNibName:@"chooseArrDepView" bundle:nil];
            [[self navigationController] pushViewController:chooseArrDepViewController animated:YES];
            [chooseArrDepViewController release], chooseArrDepViewController = nil;
        }
    }
    else {
        [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [theTable becomeFirstResponder];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

-(void)copyStationPlist
{
    NSString* bikesDictionaryPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stations" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary* bikesDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bikesDictionaryPath];

    NSArray *bikePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *bikeDocumentsDirectory = [bikePath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [bikeDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stations.plist"];

    NSString * error;
    NSData * data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:bikesDictionary format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Offcourse, the `touchesBegan` code does not work on a `tableView` because that one takes over. How can I resign the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an invisible UIButton with an action to resign the keyboard.

Also, you will want to make sure to scroll your table view so that the keyboard does not cover your text field.

Answer (score 2):

you can subclass `UITableView` and use it instead of standard `UITableView`. Why? Because You will be able to do smth like this

> ```
> - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
>     [super touvhesBegan:touches withRvrnt:event];
> }
> ```

this method will be called each time you touch your table. so you will be able to resign your `textField` as `firstResponder` inside this method.